# Image is not fit into circle UIImageview in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, xcode8, ios9

I know it's a common question but i am stack to implement it. I have an imageview which weight and height are equal. When I pick an image from media library some image are fit into circle but some image not fit into circle imageview.

Can any one suggest me how to set any type of image set into circle image view?

**Because I want to implement to user can set his/her profile image.** so user insert any type of image or any resolution, I need to crop that image but I am not able to do this. And also I don't prefer any 3rd library.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)btnImgAct //Button Action
 {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {

        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    }

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)Info
 {

    UIImage  *pickerImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];

    pickerImage=image;

    imageDataPicker =[[NSData alloc] init];
    imageDataPicker = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickerImage, 0.1); //For resize


    if([imageDataPicker length]<2097152) //bytes 1048576
    {


        [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        picker=nil;


        [self SubmitImage1:pickerImage];



    }


-(void)SubmitImage1:(UIImage *)image
   {

EditProfileImage.image=image; //insert image into imageview

  //Create circle imageview
EditProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = EditProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
[EditProfileImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
EditProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

EditProfileImage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
EditProfileImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8fWG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2girD.png)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it that you get bad cropping? In that case try using content mode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` instead. This will fill you circle with the image.

Comment: @LGP, when I insert an image from library which is any resulation that time some image is fit into circle view but some image not fit into circle. and also can you suggest me how to resign an image. My imageview weight & height are 100.0f.

Comment: Could you show what it looks like for an image that does not fit?

Comment: hi @LGP, I have update my question. Please see the above image link. Please suggest any idea because i have no idea why I am showing unwanted issue.

Answer (score 0):

Removed a few unnecessary lines and changed the image view to do **aspect fill** of the resulting image. I have tested this and it works fine with whatever images I tried.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)Info
{
    NSData *imageDataPicker = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1); //For resize

    if([imageDataPicker length]<2097152) //bytes 1048576
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self SubmitImage1:image];
    }
}

// UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill will fill the entire view
-(void)SubmitImage1:(UIImage *)image
{
    _EditProfileImage.image = image;
    _EditProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = _EditProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2;
    _EditProfileImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _EditProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    _EditProfileImage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    _EditProfileImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
}
```